# How to make a snippet in Lift - Scala

Tags: scala, lift

What I need to do is to put one tag into html page:

```
<lift:surround with="default" at="content"> 

<span class="lift:WorkingStatus.print"></span> 

</lift:surround>
```

and to have a snippet class in appropriate snippet.* package:

```
class WorkingStatus {

  def print():String={return "<table></table>";}

  def speak = <span>Hello World</span>

  def render = "* *" #> "Hello there in span"
}
```

function will generate some html table in string which will show up in html, like in `def print()` .

So, this is something rather trivial I cannot get to work in any way. I need a Scala class which could be incorporated wherever needed in html pages, like - lets say - with `<jsp:include>` and this class should be able to connect to outer web service, get list of some data and generate html which will then be inserted on desired places... complicated enough? :)

Comment: So wait, are you saying the above code does not work for you at all? What is print() supposed to be? The render function is what places content into the span, and it isn't referring to speak or to print. It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want _this_ code to work, later I can work on it, just this simple somehow to work, but it won't. Yes, I know if I put nothing special, it will trigger render function. I intentionally left 3 fuctions as 3 choices so you people can tell me what's better approach. Any advice is welcome... thx

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong signature for the print method. Snippets' methods are NodeSeq => NodeSeq.
So the more verbose variant is  
`def print(xhtml:NodeSeq):NodeSeq={return <table></table>;}` or you can use

```
def print = "*" #> <table></table>
```

if you will need a some kind of transformation, or just:

```
def print = <table></table>
```

Comment: I need to do some logic inside  print ---> call outer web service, generate html in some - let's say - "for loop" or something, and then return generated html. I also concluded that I need that NodeSeq class, but this class is uninstantiable (cannot make new NodeSeq). I am also not much in understanding of that print = "* *" #> - what these two stars stands for?

Comment: [this page](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Binding_via_CSS_Selectors) explains the css transformation